# Discord.py fetch_members Missing acces

Tags: python, discord

I need to get a list of all members from the specified discord server.

How do I do that?

**Error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/home/sergiuf/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
           await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
         File "/home/sergiuf/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
           await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
         File "/home/sergiuf/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
           raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
       discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

**Code:**

```py
        @commands.command()
        @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
        async def members(self,ctx):
            with open('users.txt','w') as f:
                async for member in ctx.guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                    print("{},{}".format(member,member.id), file=f,)
            print("done")
```

Comment: Did you make sure the bot in your specified server has been assigned as an admin in that server? Did you make sure that the settings on your bot can read the members from the server? Did you turn on intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: The problem is solved.
I just need to turn on intents.